# Python - Checking for common cooardinate between 3D ndarray and 2D ndarray without using loops! (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

Im trying to solve a problem in which I am given 2 ndarray of booleans .
one of shape (n,m,z), denote as A, and the other (n,m), denote as B.
If I am thinking of the 3D array as an array of 'z' 2D arrays, I would like to check if for every i between 0 and z, there is at least one coordinate [x,y] that:  A[x,y,i] == B[x,y] == 1.

for example:
let A be

```
np.array([[[1,0,0],
                [0,1,0],
                [0,0,1]]
               ,
               [[0,1,0],
                [0,1,0],
                [0,1,0]],

               [[1,0,0],
                [0,1,0],
                [0,0,1]]])
```

and B be:

```
> [[1,0,0],
   [0,1,0],
   [0,0,1]])
```

The function should return True!

I need to solve it without any loops (just numpy tools)!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(np.logical_and(a == 1, a == b).sum((1,2)) >= 1).sum() == a.shape[0]
```

`np.logical_and(a == 1, a == b)` gives you the boolean mask for every 2D row. `sum((1,2))` gives the count of matches in each row. We don't care if it's 1 or more so we get the `>= 1` and count them using `sum()`. This must be equal to the number of rows `a.shape[0]`

Edit: `(1,2)` are the axes we want to see equivalency for. In case axes are `x,y,z` then the sum should be over `(0,1)` instead of `(1,2)` which would correspond to `x,y` instead of `y,z`. However, the array `a` representation is made where `z` here is the first axis.